# javascript logical operators are not working

Tags: javascript

I am createing discord bot, that will do a coinflip, but i got some logical operator errors that i cant figure out whats wrong. I want that bot will respond on command if its not full command and between some strings it doesnt work. Here is whats wrong - If I type !coinflip blue - it works, the bot respond me to "choose currency" BUT IF I TYPE !coinflip red - then bot still thinks that theres nothing after !coinflip and it will say "choose a side". Please help.

```
if (args[0] !== ('blue'||'red')) {
    message.reply('If you do not know how to create coinflip type **!help**');
    message.reply('Choose a side [blue, red]. [Example: !coinflip **blue**].');

  } else if (args[0] === ( 'blue' || 'red' )) {
        if (args[1] !== 'ref' || args[1] !== 'key') {
          message.reply('*If you do not know how to create coinflip type **!help***');
          message.reply('Choose a currency [ref, key]. [Example: !coinflip blue **key**].');
    } else if (args[1] === 'ref' || args[1] === 'key') {etc...}
```

Comment: `'blue'||'red'` always evaluates to `blue`, since it's a truthy value, check each value independently.

Comment: `args[0] !== 'blue' || args[0] !== 'red'`

Comment: Or use a switch-statement.

Comment: `!['blue', 'red'].includes(arg[0])`

Comment: do you mean new if statements ??? thats a lot of coding... is there any other way ??

Comment: After you fix the obvious issue with values being more than one option, I have a feeling you have a big logic error. You need to layout the logic so the most specific things are at the top and the least are at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this:

```js
if (args[0] !== ('blue'||'red')) {
```

As any of the following:

```js
if (args[0] !== 'blue' && args[0] !== 'red') {
```

```js
if (!['blue', 'red'].includes(args[0])) {
```

```js
if (!/blue|red/.test(args[0])) {
```

This last option resembles your current attempt most closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (args[0] !== ('blue'||'red')) {
```

Needs to be

```
if ((args[0] !== 'blue') && (args[0] !== 'red')) {
```

`'blue'||'red'` will just be 'blue', which isn't what you want, assuming you want to compare args[0] to 'blue' and 'red'

Comment: i made changes but when i wrote !coinflip red, it didnt show anything